# MySQL - Running count in MySQL with multiple condition

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3...
```

It can have up to 20 conditions. I would like to obtained the count of the table after each condition. More specifically I want to know the count of

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3;
...
```

One way I can think of is to create a bunch of temporary table. Then the next sub-query will use the previous temporary table. It will looks something like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (select * from table WHERE condition1);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 (select * from t1 WHERE condition2);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t3 (select * from t2 WHERE condition3);
...
```

then I can count each of those temporary table. I wonder whether there is any better option that is faster and probably does not requre creating a bunch of temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below query, if that works for you:

This will fetch results from all the conditions and then we can count based on the required condition using `CASE`

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 AND condition2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count12,
SUM(CASE WHEN condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count123,
FROM table 
WHERE 
condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3;
```